# Injecting a x86 target with a x86 dll from a x64 injector

Tags: c++, windows, dll, 64-bit

I'm having a bit of trouble doing exactly what the title says... I made an injector that works with x86 to x86 and x64 to x64, but injecting x86 from a x64 (with a x86 dll) doesn't work with that code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

bool InjectDll(DWORD processId, std::string dllPath)
{
    HANDLE hThread, hProcess;
    void*  pLibRemote = 0;  // the address (in the remote process) where
                            // szLibPath will be copied to;

    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");

    char DllFullPathName[_MAX_PATH];
    GetFullPathName(dllPath.c_str(), _MAX_PATH, DllFullPathName, NULL);

    // Get process handle
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processId);

    // copy file path in szLibPath
    char szLibPath[_MAX_PATH];
    strcpy_s(szLibPath, DllFullPathName);

    // 1. Allocate memory in the remote process for szLibPath
    pLibRemote = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, sizeof(szLibPath),
                                MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

    if (pLibRemote == NULL)
        return false;

    // 2. Write szLibPath to the allocated memory
    WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, pLibRemote, (void*)szLibPath,
                       sizeof(szLibPath), NULL);

    // 3. Force remote process to load dll
    LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE thread;
    thread = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32,"LoadLibraryA");

    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, NULL, 0, thread,  pLibRemote,
                                 0, NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

The function returns true in every scenario (even from a 64 bit injector injecting a 32bit process), yet it fails to actually inject the dll.

By the way, during my research I found those questions:

[x86 Code Injection into an x86 Process from a x64 Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13297452/x86-code-injection-into-an-x86-process-from-a-x64-process)

[C++: Injecting 32 bit targets from 64 bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776437/c-injecting-32-bit-targets-from-64-bit-process)

But while the answers explain how, I didn't manage to actually do it... so maybe all I need is a code snippet to send me on the right way?

Comment: No, this cannot work at all.  The address you obtained from GetProcAddress() will be completely wrong.  There is no simple workaround for that but one, build the x64 version of your program.

Comment: The INJECTOR is 64 bit, the DLL is 32 bit, and the TARGET is 32 bit. There is no reason why it would not work. The 2 questions I linked in my posts all says it's possible and many people managed to do it... So why would you claim it's not possible?

Comment: *The address you obtained from GetProcAddress() will be completely wrong*.  Feel free to ignore it.  The hack that @zah proposed is not a bad one btw, not terribly practical.  As long as you do this, might as well build the 32-bit version of the injector and start it from the 64-bit version.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I saw @zah answer but I dismissed it as it wasn't chosen as the answer and it felt wrong, but if you say it looks good I will give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this line:

```
thread = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)GetProcAddress(hKernel32,"LoadLibraryA");
```

for this line:

```
thread = (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)system("loadLibrary_x86_address.exe");
```

with "loadLibrary_x86_address.exe" being a 32 bit app defined as:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    return (int)LoadLibraryA;
}
```

Works! It's kind of a hack, but it does the job.